# Cucumber\Rest Assured: How to get the request specs?

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured

I have the following step:

```
@Given("Request specifications are set with base uri {string}")
public void setRequestsSpec(String baseUri){

    requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setBaseUri(baseUri)
            .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())//log request and response for better debugging. You can also only log if a requests fails.
            .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
            .addFilter(new RcAllureFilter())
            .build();
```

Then I have:

```
@When("^Azure Login Request Executed$")
public void azureLoginExecuted() {

    response =
    given()  //Add x-www-form-urlencoded body params:
        .spec(testContext().getRequestSpec())
        .formParam(GRANT_TYPE_KEY, GRANT_TYPE_VALUE)
        .formParam(AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_ID_KEY, AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_ID_VALUE)
        .formParam(AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY, AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE)
        .formParam(RESOURCE_KEY, RESOURCE_VALUE)
    .when()
        .post(AUTO_TEAM_TENANT_ID + RESOURCE); //Send the request along with the resource

    setAuthorizationToken();
}
```

How can I extract the request's details like URI, headers and parameters from it?
I cannot find a class from which I can extract the request details.
In RequestSpecification class, I hardly can find any getter functions in this class.
I need this values in order to build a formatted log message.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to get the details from requestspecification, then you can use like this .

```
RequestSpecification spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().setContentType(ContentType.JSON).addHeader("h1", "h2")
                .build();
        QueryableRequestSpecification queryable = SpecificationQuerier.query(spec);

        System.out.println(" Content is  " + queryable.getContentType());
        System.out.println(" Header is  " + queryable.getHeaders().getValue("h1"));
```

But in your scenario, you want request details too. so , best way would be to use a requestlogging filter, which accepts a PrintStream (which in turn can work With ByteArrayOutPutStream which can convert to a String ) . Basic idea is, to use RequestLoggingFilter with a PRintStream and then use any code to save PrintStream to a String. You can usr StringWriter too.

```
RequestSpecification spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().build();
    StringWriter requestWriter = new StringWriter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(baos);

    Response response = given().spec(spec).contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(printStream)).get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    printStream.flush();
    System.out.println(baos);
```